# How to convert list to datatable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

```
var Query = dbContext.GetUserDetailsForAutoMail().AsEnumerable().ToList();    
dt1 = Query.CopyToDataTable();
```

I want to convert a `List` to `DataTable` using LINQ without looping.

In the above code `GetUserDetailsForAutoMail()` is storedprocedure, the result can be stored in an query, after it can be convert into a `DataTable` but it throws an error like

> Error  1   The type 'AutoSendigEmail.GetUserDetailsForAutoMail_Result' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AutoSendigEmail.GetUserDetailsForAutoMail_Result' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. D:\Deva\AutoSendigEmail\AutoSendigEmail\Service1.cs 68  23  AutoSendigEmail

Comment: Thank u.... i got the result